# iOS 8 Beta 4 CLLocationManager not working Placemark null

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ios8

I have a Singleton Class with my Location Manager and the reverse geocoding is in my Viewcontroller to print the address in the app.

Everything worked fine till the new iOS 8 Beta 4 appeared and now the reverse geocoding doesn't work -- the placemark comes back null every time.

It works on the iOS 8 simulator but it doesn't work in my iPhone 5S with beta 4 installed.

My Singleton .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;

@end

@interface TSLocationHandler : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<LocationHandlerDelegate> delegate;


+(id)getSharedInstance;
-(void)startUpdating;
-(void)stopUpdating;
-(void)requestWhenInUseAuthorization;

@end
```

My Singleton .m

```
#import "TSLocationHandler.h"

static TSLocationHandler *DefaultManager;

@interface TSLocationHandler()

-(void)initiate;

@end


@implementation TSLocationHandler


+(id)getSharedInstance
{

    if (!DefaultManager) {

        DefaultManager=[[self allocWithZone:NULL]init];
        [DefaultManager initiate];  
    }
    return DefaultManager;
}
-(void)initiate{

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
}

-(void)startUpdating{

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) stopUpdating{

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)requestWhenInUseAuthorization
{

    float ver =[[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];

    if (ver>=8.0) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }else{
    }
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!error==0) {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"An error as ocurred during the process of retrieving your location. Please Make sure that you have internet and that you have granted the app with authorization to get your location." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }
} 
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    if  ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(locationManager:didUpdateLocations:)])
    {
        [self.delegate locationManager:manager didUpdateLocations:locations];
    }
}

@end
```

My ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self hasInternet];

    //Core Location
    [[TSLocationHandler getSharedInstance]requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [[TSLocationHandler getSharedInstance]setDelegate:self];
    [[TSLocationHandler getSharedInstance]startUpdating];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    geoCoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"PLACEMARK: %@",placeMark.thoroughfare);
        NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);

        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placeMark = [placemarks lastObject];


            NSLog(@"PLACEMARK: %@", placeMark.thoroughfare);

            self.userLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",placeMark.thoroughfare,placeMark.locality];

            [[TSLocationHandler getSharedInstance]stopUpdating];

            [self performSelector:@selector(espera) withObject:self afterDelay:4];
        } else {

            NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
            NSLog(@"PLACEMARK: %@", placeMark.thoroughfare);
            NSLog(@"GEOCODE: %@",geoCoder);
        }
   } ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

The iOS 8 simulator in Beta 4 does not set "Allow Location Access" for your app by default, it looks like a bug to me. You must go to the Settings App, Go to Privacy > Location, turn on Location Services, then go to Allow Location Access, select Always, then select your app (just above System Services) and an select "Always" for Allow Location Access.

Second, you should look at the documentation carefully, specifically [Listing 1.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). You are invoking the geolocation service immediately vs. waiting for "recent" update.

After doing all of this, geolocation works. It is necessary to change location using Debug/Location functions in the Simulator menu. I usually set a custom location, then select City Bicycle Ride to force didUpdateLocations to fire.

Also, note, you should not make changes to location quicker than about 10 seconds and expect geolocation to respond, it will return an error (something like the URL is invalid) to prevent overuse/DoS on the server.

Making modifications to your code similar to what's shown below might work better:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
    geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (placemarks != nil) {
            self.zip = [placemarks[0] postalCode];
            NSLog(@"Got a zip code: %@", self.zip);
        } else if(error.code == kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult) {
            NSLog(@"%s, %@", __func__, @"No result yet.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%s, geocoding failed, erro: %@", __func__, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Remember... if you reset the Simulator Content and Settings or delete your app in the simulator, you'll need to change the settings again.

Comment: Hello, it was a bug yes. everything it's ok now. but your code is right. I while do the timeStamp change to my code. Thank's

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turning on Location services was helpful.